# Html files do not work in Python from Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have a problem with the html file in Python Django.
This is my code:

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

  <p>Topics</p>

  <ul>
    {% for topic in topics %}
      <li>
        <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic.id %}">{{ topic }}</a>
      </li>
    {% empty %}
      <li>No topics have been added yet.</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>

{% endblock content %}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Yeah, you've not got Django rendering the template. Is your server even running? You've just opened the `.html` file directly

Comment: When I open the html file directly, the page looks exactly as shown in the picture.

Comment: When I type python manage.py runserver I get this message:

TemplateSyntaxError at /
'block' tag takes only one argument
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 3.1.4
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:
'block' tag takes only one argument

Comment: Ok, so that's your actual issue. This question is irrelevant as it is, because it's got nothing to do with your issue

Comment: So where is the problem?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think Django is rendering the template, did you just opened the HTML file directly?
run `python manage.py`

Comment: We already know that they're not because they stated so in comments and listed a different issue?

Comment: @brian yeap The photo uploaded to the first post is the photo when I open the file directly in the browser.
When running the program, I get this message in the browser (of course, this is only part of the page because the entire page shows errors):
>TemplateSyntaxError at / 'block' tag takes only one argument
>Request Method: GET Request URL: 127.0.0.1:8000
>Django Version: 3.1.4
>Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
>Exception Value: 'block' tag takes only one argument

Comment: how does your base.html look like? Can you share you're your base.html?

Comment: @brianyeap 
<p>
  <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:index' %}">Learning Log</a> -
  <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topics' %}">Topics</a>
</p>

{% block content %}{% endblock content %}

Comment: @AdrianSzymanski hi, sorry I couldn't find any problem. Your code looks fine to me.

Comment: @brianyeap For me too, so I don't know why it doesn't work. Thx anyway.